# Parity error -32010 Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. Limit: 4703218, got: 4712388. Try decreasing supplied gas

Tags: parity, gas-limit

I am playing with a private blockchain.  I get this error when I try to deploy a contract:

> [-32010] Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. Limit: 4703218,
>   got: 4712388. Try decreasing supplied gas.

This is weird because the chain spec file specifically has this parameter:

> "gasLimit": "4712388"

It brings up two questions:

1. Where is "4703218" coming from as the limit (since 4712388 is specified)
2. Where is "4712388" coming from as the default amount of supplied gas?

Please see that I said private blockchain.  The only miner is mine.

Comment: The error appears when a transaction was submitted with gas set above the block gas limit. You have to always set the transaction gas below the block gas limit. The block gas limit is dynamic, miners can increase or decrease it over time. Most ethereum clients provides some mechanisms to configure it after the network has deployed: geth `--targetgaslimit`, and parity `--gas-floor-target`.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you but this doesn't answer what I'm asking.  Seems like you're off on something else.